Take your seats
Given a number of persons and same number of seats, where every person has a seat assigned.
Some persons do know their seat, and, some do not know, perhaps forgot, or lost reference to, their seat.
Everyone is kindly asked to take their seat.
Persons who do not know their seat, take a random free seat. Persons who do know their seat, take their seat if it is free, and otherwise take a random free seat.
There are no collisions (multiple persons taking same seat). Seats are taken sequentially one by one.
Also: seats are taken in no predetermined order. Assume every possible order has equal probability.
Clearly everyone now has a determined probability to end up in assigned seat.
Given that both the number of persons who do, and, the number of persons who do not know their seat, are less or equal to 13, and, furthermore, given that the 7th person in the seat taking order limited to those who do know their seat has 75% chance to end up in assigned seat:
Question: "what is the number of seats, and, what is the number of persons who do not know their seat?".
Bonus: "do any persons who do not know their seat, have more than 10% chance to end up in assigned seat?". If so, which ones (in the seat taking order limited to those who did not know their seat).
The puzzle is loosely based upon and inspired by question

 Hamlet and the theatre (which I had not heard about, but noticed to appear top of 'Related' list).

and (same, older)

 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5595 "Taking Seats on a Plane" (which I happened to run into recently).

hint:

 one may need need to generalize these equal questions and their answer.


Why did you tighten the search space?

@AxiomaticSystem : because there might be multiple solutions in case it is loosened and ,,, I admit ... also because for larger numbers the computation becomes slow on my equipment :) especially perhaps for the bonus. So I went the easy fast way out ...

Only one class satisfies the original constraint (26 or fewer seats). The next solution is a class of 27 students, 15 of which know their assigned seats.

@AxiomaticSystem : fwiw ... I had meanwhile changed constraint from sum<=26 to each term<=13 ... because that how I effectively limited my search space.

Suppose there are $k$ people who Know their seat, and some number of people who Lost their seat, competing for $s$ seats.

 In order to calculate the probability that the seventh Knower's seat is available in terms of $k$ and $s$, we need to evaluate each number of Losers, and find the probability that that many Losers precede the seventh Knower in the queue and the probability that none of them take the seventh Knower's seat.

To help ourselves along, we notice that

 in all cases, we can assume that all the Losers that precede the sevent Knower succeed the sixth. Anytime a Knower would find that his/her seat is occupied (by a Loser), the set of possible outcomes is the same as if the Knower had switched places with the Loser and found his/her seat first. If a Knower's seat is occupied by another Knower, then there must be an initial Loser to whom this argument can be applied.


 With this simplification, the probability that none of $l$ losers take the seventh Knower's seat is simply the number of $l$-seat sequences from $s-7$ seats divided by the number of $l$-seat sequences from $s-6$ seats: $\frac{\frac{(s-7)!}{(s-7-l)!}}{\frac{(s-6)!}{(s-6-l)!}} = \frac{s-6-l}{s-6}$


 The probability that exactly $l$ Losers precede the seventh Knower is precisely the numbers of sequences with six Knowers among the first $l+6$ positions, and $k-7$ Knowers among the last $s-l-7$ positions, divided by the total number of sequences. We have $P(l) = \frac{\binom{l+6}{6}\binom{s-l-7}{k-7}}{\binom{s}{k}}$.

This is unfortunate (at least for my level of combinatorial knowledge), but what is fortunate is that this is a computer-puzzle,

 and some Python tells me that a class of 13 Knowers and 7 Losers vying for 20 seats correctly seats the seventh Knower ¾ of the time.
binom = [[1]]
K = 7 #Knower to be seated
k = K #Number of Knowers
P,Q = (3,4) #Chance to seat target Knower
for s in range(1,10000):
    binom.append(list(map(lambda x,y:x+y,binom[-1]+[0],[0]+binom[-1])))
    if s < k: continue
    num,denom = sum((s+1-K-l)*binom[l+K-1][K-1]*binom[s-l-K][k-K] for l in range(s-k+1)),(s+1-K)*binom[s][k]
    if P*denom == Q*num: print(s,k)
    if P*denom > Q*num: k += 1

Bonus: Now that we know the class size, the path we take is a little different.

 For each Loser in the class, we need to iterate over the number of Knowers $K$ ahead of him/her. The probability, for a given $K$, that the Loser's seat isn't taken by any of the $L$ preceding Losers is $\frac{s-K-L}{s-K}$, and the total chance that the Loser picks his/her seat is simply $\frac{1}{s-K}$.


 The chance that $K$ Knowers precede the Loser is $\frac{\binom{K+L}{K}\binom{s-K-L-1}{k-K}}{\binom{s}{k}}$, by similar reasoning to that used in the main problem.

And by the power of judicious code reuse, we have

 that the last two Losers have chances of 10.3% and 12%, respectively, to find their seats, and that every other Loser's chance is too low:
def gcd(a,b):
    if min(a,b)==0: return max(a,b)
    return gcd(b,a%b)
simp = lambda a,b:(a//gcd(a,b),b//gcd(a,b))

s,k = 20,13 #Class size and Knower amount
P,Q = 1,10 #Minimal chance to seat Loser
binom = [[1]]
for i in range(1,s+1): binom.append(list(map(lambda x,y:x+y,binom[-1]+[0],[0]+binom[-1])))
for L in range(s-k):
    num,denom=0,1
    for K in range(k+1):
        n,d = binom[K+L][K]*binom[s-K-L-1][k-K],(s-K)*binom[s][k]
        num,denom = simp(n*denom+d*num,d*denom)
    if P*denom <= Q*num: print(L,num/denom)


Great, now what about bonus?

Feel free to share evolving computer code, I might one day do so as well if all is settled.

@FirstNameLastName I've whipped something up for the Bonus.

Nice. your answers are correct. I will accept tomorrow unless some even more spectacular answer is given.

This is not an official answer, rather some, hopefully informative, explanation about the puzzle.
Compliments to @AxiomaticSystem for clever solution
The equal PSE and MSE question (in OP) hides some more probabilities. In fact there are formulas for these probabilities in terms of position p in ordered seating of all persons (who do or do not know their seat).
Let's call a-persons those who do not know their seat and b-persons those who do know their seat. Then

 
 probability b-person p to end up on own chair given a a-persons seated already is
 pb(p,a,n) = (n - p + 1) / (n - p + 1 + a)
 

Special case in PSE and MSE question: a = 1 and p = n we get

 pb(n,1,n) = (n - n + 1) / (n - n + 1 + 1) = 1 / 2

Same for (not part of PSE and MSE question)

 
 probability for a-person to end up on own chair given b b-persons seated already
 pa(b,n) = 1 / (n - b)
 

Special case in PSE and MSE question: b = 0 (and p = 1 but formula is independent of p) we get

 pa(b,n) = 1 / (n - b) = 1 / n

I leave proof of both probability formulas pa and pb as exercise :)
So now we can average over all, possible orders. I did so in Julia code:
using Combinatorics

# a-persons do not know own chair
# b-persons do know own chair

# probability for a-person to end up on own chair given b b-persons seated already
pa(b,n) = 1 // (n - b)

# probability b-person p to end up on own chair given a a-persons seated already
pb(p,a,n) = (n - p + 1) // (n - p + 1 + a)

# A = number of a-persons
# B = number of b-persons
function solution(A, B)
    # number of persons and chairs
    N = A + B

    println("solution A=$A B=$B N=$N")

    # all possible orders for persons to be seated
    # each order is given by array of positions of a-persons in the order
    Os = collect(combinations(1 : N, A))
    S = length(Os)

    # rational counts of a-persons ending up on own chair
    As = zeros(Rational, A)
    # rational counts of b-persons ending up on own chair
    Bs = zeros(Rational, B)

    # loop over all sitting orders
    for o in Os
        a = 0
        b = 0
        for p in 1 : N
            if p in o
                a += 1
                As[a] += pa(b,N)
            else
                b += 1
                Bs[b] += pb(p,a,N)
            end
        end
    end

    # calculate mean
    for a in 1 : A
        As[a] //= S
    end
    for b in 1 : B
        Bs[b] //= S
    end

    # show results
    for a in 1 : A
        p = As[a]
        q = convert(Float64,p)
        println("p = $q = $p a #$a")
    end
    for b in 1 : B
        p = Bs[b] 
        q = convert(Float64,p)
        println("p = $q = $p b #$b")
    end

    println()
end

M = 13

for x in 0 : M
    for y in 0 : M
        # increment b-persons first
        solution(y,x)
    end
end

It now is a matter of spotting nice figures in the output. Most probabilities are ugly and most nice ones have multiple occurrences. Also, for large numbers, the (at least my) code is not fast. So I limited search space to maximum 13 a-persons and 13 b-persons.

 I spotted a single occurrence of nice probability 3/4 for b-person 7, namely: in case of 7 a-persons and 13 b-persons. Then, for the a-persons in that solution, it seems latest 2 have probability bigger than 1/10.

Below is the relevant output (but to assure single occurrence of 3/4 for b-person 7 one needs to inspect entire output)
solution A=7 B=13 N=20
p = 0.05507027527937492 = 331267517359//6015359750400 a #1
p = 0.06114531479876027 = 2919135441//47740950400 a #2
p = 0.0685038430340926 = 118925039//1736034560 a #3
p = 0.0775162712070535 = 302784583//3906077760 a #4
p = 0.08867677956825928 = 76972977//868017280 a #5
p = 0.10264644086348143 = 222747211//2170043200 a #6
p = 0.12031090382081897 = 361495189//3004675200 a #7
p = 0.975 = 39//40 b #1
p = 0.9473684210526315 = 18//19 b #2
p = 0.9166666666666666 = 11//12 b #3
p = 0.8823529411764706 = 15//17 b #4
p = 0.84375 = 27//32 b #5
p = 0.8 = 4//5 b #6
p = 0.75 = 3//4 b #7
p = 0.6923076923076923 = 9//13 b #8
p = 0.625 = 5//8 b #9
p = 0.5454545454545454 = 6//11 b #10
p = 0.45 = 9//20 b #11
p = 0.3333333333333333 = 1//3 b #12
p = 0.1875 = 3//16 b #13

$ julia Julia/pse128954.jl | grep '0\.75 ='
p = 0.75 = 3//4 a #1
p = 0.75 = 3//4 b #1
p = 0.75 = 3//4 b #1
p = 0.75 = 3//4 b #2
p = 0.75 = 3//4 b #2
p = 0.75 = 3//4 b #3
p = 0.75 = 3//4 b #2
p = 0.75 = 3//4 b #6
p = 0.75 = 3//4 b #5
p = 0.75 = 3//4 b #4
p = 0.75 = 3//4 b #3
p = 0.75 = 3//4 b #5
p = 0.75 = 3//4 b #4
p = 0.75 = 3//4 b #6
p = 0.75 = 3//4 b #7 <<-- single occurrence

@AxiomaticSystem: I ran your code and noticed exact same values where I assume you count from 0
$ python pse128954.py
5 0.10264644086348143
6 0.12031090382081897

